# Coldfusion: I need to change a struct value when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, struct, coldfusion

The code dynamically creates purchase orders with checkboxes as well as builds a struct with the key being the PO number and the value is false. I need to switch the struct value to true when the checkbox is checked.

```
<!--- declare an array to hold the structs. --->
<cfset checkedPOsArray = ArrayNew(1)>

<!--- dynamically create the po checkboxes --->
<cfloop query="someQuery">
    <input type="checkbox" name="po_number_#someQuery.PoNumber#" onClick="changeStructValue(#someQuery.PoNumber#)" value="1" />

    <!--- declare a variable to hold each po number. --->
    <cfset thisPONumber = "#someQuery.po_number#">

    <!--- build a struct to hold the booleen values. --->
    <cfset thisPO_st = StructNew()>
    <cfset thisPO_st.isChecked_[variables.thisPONumber] = false>

    <!--- append the structs to the array --->                      
    <cfset ArrayAppend(variables.checkedPOsArray, thisPO_st)>
</cfloop>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeStructValue(poNum) {
        // grab the specific input that was checked.
        var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=po_number_" + poNum + "]");

        if(checkbox.checked) 
        {   
            // set the value of the ischecked struct field to true.
            document.checkedPOsArray.indexOf(thisPO_st.isChecked_[poNum]).value = true;
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see where you declare the `selectedPlantsArray`

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to complicate something very simple.  When you post a form with checkboxes, only the checked boxes are included in the form scope on the page to which the form is posted.  To me, that makes everything you are trying to accomplish in this question unnecessary.

Comment: @DustinSiegel What are you trying to achieve? Unless I'm reading this wrong, you are confusing server-side and client-side code as well as the persistence of variables. In basic terms, a client requests a page from a server which then returns it. Once the page is loaded in the client, the server-side code and variables are no longer available. You are then working solely in the client unless you make another call back to the server. Provide more info.

Comment: @DanRoberts Great Question! I need to be able to pass the struct through session when the user paginates to the next page so that I can add the previously selected po's to the form. The server is called agian when they move between pages.

Comment: @alanfcm I messed up and forgot to change the name of the array to checkedPOsArray when transferring the code to stack overflow. It has been edited to correct for that.

Comment: @DustinSiegel DanRoberts is correct in that you are trying to mix client side code (javascript) and server side code (cfml) which cannot directly communicate.  Your variable CFM variables do not exist in <script> tags unless manually output (not what you want to do here).

You need to have some code checking for something like 
```<cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>```

Then you can check Form variables for your html inputs and modify your CFM variables.